# how to determine what url:port and angular2 component is being launched from

Tags: angular, typescript

from an angular 2 component, I need to determine the url:port that my container application is running at.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: this really isn't an Angular question, but rather a plain javascript question

Comment: Why dont you use window.location man ?

Comment: document.location.host does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

document.location.host does the magic